# Can I make my tp-link router prioritise my machine over others?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I live in a house share with 7 flatmates. It has a TP-Link Model No. TL-WA901ND.

```
Firmware Version:   
3.16.9 Build 150409 Rel.60640n
Hardware Version:   
WA901ND v3 00000000
```

(I installed the latest firmware for the hardware version).

Even though it says "300Mbps Wireless N Access Point", tt's very slow most of the time so that I can't have a smooth Whatsapp call.
I live a floor above the access point, so it can be because of distance (though I have a full signal sign) but I suspect it also has to do with the amount of load.

Sometimes when I have an important Whatsapp call to make, I change the SSID to an unrecognizable name and put a password on, so I have the wifi all to myself - and then my connection is smooth.

Sadly I can't do it all the time because the flatmates will complain, try to restart the router, etc.

Do you have a way to make the router prioritize my machine, or in another way improve my experience?

Comment: 300Mbps and all speeds you see on the box are marketing values and theoretical max speeds. Can you create 2 SSID on the AP? One for you and one for your flatmates. Put the priority on low for your flatmates SSID and perhaps a rate limit too.

Answer (score 1):

You can prioritize your machine, but very likely not with the standard firmware.

OpenWRT [can](https://openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wa901nd) be installed in the WA901ND, but the description says it has low RAM, and won't be supported in the future. (Low RAM may be another reason your existing setup is slow).

Once you have an open-source firmware installed, you can use the traffic control/QoS ("Quality of Service") features to prioritize your machine. I'd assume there are ready-made packages for OpenWRT or derivates like DD-WRT somewhere.

**However**, in your place the first thing I'd do is to invest the 30 EUR or so and buy a router with more RAM (can be TP-Link again), and make sure to choose a model that will work well with open firmware.

Comment: Do you have a suggested model for my case? Also, I am currently connecting to a tplink configured as an access point, with the main one being downstairs. I wonder if I need something that would act as an access point as well.